# Using SWT in Gradle could not resolve all dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gradle, swt

I'm trying to use the latest Eclipse SWT 3.114.0 in my Gradle project, but I get the following:

```
   > Could not find org.eclipse.platform:org.eclipse.swt.${osgi.platform}:3.114.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.swt.${osgi.platform}/3.114.0/org.eclipse.swt.${osgi.platform}-3.114.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.swt.${osgi.platform}/3.114.0/org.eclipse.swt.${osgi.platform}-3.114.0.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/voark/IdeaProjects/Eden-Dev/newlauncher/libs/org.eclipse.swt.${osgi.platform}-3.114.0.jar
       - file:/C:/Users/voark/IdeaProjects/Eden-Dev/newlauncher/libs/org.eclipse.swt.${osgi.platform}.jar
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/swt/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.swt.${osgi.platform}/3.114.0/org.eclipse.swt.${osgi.platform}-3.114.0.pom
     Required by:
         project : > org.eclipse.platform:org.eclipse.swt:3.114.0

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

This is my `build.gradle`:

```
import org.gradle.api.JavaVersion

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:5.2.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

mainClassName = 'com.legacypk.newlauncher.Main'

group 'com.legacypk'
version '1.0.0'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.platform', name: 'org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64', version: '3.114.0'
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.platform', name: 'org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64', version: '3.114.0'
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.platform', name: 'org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64', version: '3.114.0'
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.platform', name: 'org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.ppc64le', version: '3.114.0'

    compile name: 'DJNativeSwing'
    compile name: 'DJNativeSwing-SWT'
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, SWT is being officially distributed on Maven Central now, so you should probably add `mavenCentral()` to your repositories block.

Secondly, the maven property `osgi.platform` doesn't seem to be handled by gradle. Instead, you'll have to do a bit of special dependency resolution to correctly grab the platform specific dependencies.

The following should work fine (lifted from https://github.com/LWJGLX/lwjgl3-swt/blob/master/build.gradle)

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        dependencySubstitution {
            def os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase()
            if (os.contains("windows")) {
                substitute module('org.eclipse.platform:org.eclipse.swt.${osgi.platform}') with module("org.eclipse.platform:org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64:3.114.0")
            }
            else if (os.contains("linux")) {
                substitute module('org.eclipse.platform:org.eclipse.swt.${osgi.platform}') with module("org.eclipse.platform:org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64:3.114.0")
            }
            else if (os.contains("mac")) {
                substitute module('org.eclipse.platform:org.eclipse.swt.${osgi.platform}') with module("org.eclipse.platform:org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64:3.114.0")
            }
        }
    }
}
```